# Prevent yargs from accepting invalid inputs

Tags: node.js, yargs

I've got a typescript program that I'm trying to use yargs with, but I'm having trouble getting yargs to correctly detect invalid commands:

```
let test = yargs.command('test', '');
test.strict();
let args = test.parse(['fake', 'blah', 'test', 'whydoesitacceptthis']);
```

Why does yargs accept this? Also, the resulting `args` parses flags correctly, but `args._` (which is the non-flag arguments) becomes `['test', 'fake', 'blah', 'test', 'whydoesitacceptthis']`. How do I prevent yargs from accepting invalid commands?